# How to use SFTP connection in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using plugin called **ftp-simple** in visual studio code. I tried to remote connect to my site files but it don't login now showing error message. I have added the `.ppk` string and host name etc. my config file look like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "LIVE",
        "host": "00.0.0.0",
        "port": 21,
        "type": "sftp",
        "username": "mysuername",
        "password": "",
        "privateKey": "some long string",
        "path": "/path/to/site",
        "autosave": true,
        "confirm": true
    }
]
```

Comment: Which config file? Can you provide a filename?